# What is the exact meaning of "he was assumed my rapture"?

Tags: meaning

In this this sentence "he was assumed my rapture", does the author mean that the character is in rapture over something ? Is there a subtle nuance ? I can't find anywhere the expression "assumed by rapture".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"He was assumed my rapture," makes *no* sense in English. "He was *consumed by* rapture," though, means he was so enraptured or enchanted, so overcome by emotion, that his intellect was "consumed"; i.e. he was unable to think, just to perceive.

Comment: Thanks. Yet, those are the very word in the article I read. Maybe an error.  Thanks a lot for your explanations!